# Julia: optimize simulation of simple dynamical system

Tags: performance, optimization, dynamic-programming, julia

I am trying to optimize the simulation of a simple dynamical system in which the response of a network as well as its parameters (weights) evolve according to simple linear equations. The simulation needs to run for tens of millions of time steps, but the network size will typically be small. Hence, performance is bound less so by matrix-vector products but rather by temporary arrays, bound checks and other less visible factors. Since I am new to Julia, I'd appreciate any hints to further optimize performance.

```
function train_network(A, T, Of, cs, dt)
    N, I = size(T)
    z    = zeros(I)
    r    = zeros(N)

    @inbounds for t in 1:size(cs, 1)
        # precompute
        Az  = A*z
        Ofr = Of*r

        # compute training signal
        @devec z += dt.*(Az + cs[t] - 0.5.*z)
        I_teach   = T*(Az + cs[t])
        Tz        = T*z

        # rate updates
        @devec r += dt.*(I_teach - Ofr - 0.1.*r)

        # weight updates
        for i in 1:I
            @devec T[:, i] += dt.*1e-3.*(z[i].*r - T[:, i])
        end

        for n in 1:N
            @devec Of[:, n] += dt.*1e-3.*(Tz.*r[n] - Of[:, n])     
        end
    end
end

# init parameters
N, I = 20, 2
dt  = 1e-3

# init weights
T = rand(N, I)*N
A = rand(I, I)
Of = rand(N, N)/N

# simulation time & input
sim_T = 2000
ts = 0:dt:sim_T
cs = randn(size(ts, 1), I)
```

Timing the network (2.000.000 steps) with

```
@time train_network(A, T, Of, cs, dt)
```

yields the timings

```
3.420486 seconds (26.12 M allocations: 2.299 GB, 6.65% gc time)
```

**Update 1**

Following the advice by David Sanders I got rid of the devec macro and wrote out the loops. This indeed reduces array allocations and boosts performance by about 25%, here are the new numbers:

```
2.648113 seconds (18.00 M allocations: 1.669 GB, 5.60% gc time)
```

The smaller the network size, the bigger the boost. A gist of the updated simulation code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/wielandbrendel/c03c91f78b9a209f2a8d).

**Update 2**

Much of the memory allocations are due to the matrix-vector products. So, in order to get rid of those I replaced those products by an in-place BLAS operation, BLAS.genv!, which reduces timings by another 25% and memory allocation by 90%,

```
1.990031 seconds (2.00 M allocations: 152.589 MB, 0.69% gc time)
```

Updated code [here](https://gist.github.com/wielandbrendel/c03c91f78b9a209f2a8d).

**Update 3**

The largest rank-1 update can also be replaced by two calls to in-place BLAS functions, namely BLAS.scal! for scaling and BLAS.ger! for a rank-1 update. The caveat is that both calls are fairly slow if more then one thread is used (problem with OpenBLAS?), so it is best to set

```
blas_set_num_threads(1)
```

There is a 15% gain in timings for a network size of 20, and a gain of 50% for a network of size 50. There are no more memory allocations, and the new timings are

```
1.638287 seconds (11 allocations: 1.266 KB)
```

Again, the updated code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/wielandbrendel/c03c91f78b9a209f2a8d).

**Update 4**

I wrote a basic [Cython script](https://gist.github.com/wielandbrendel/5ee1457722cb6706240b) to compare the results so far. The main difference is that I do not use any calls to BLAS but have loops: Injecting low-level BLAS calls is a pain in Cython, and calls to numpy dot have too much overhead for small network sizes (I tried...). Timings are

```
CPU times: user 3.46 s, sys: 6 ms, total: 3.47 s, Wall time: 3.47 s
```

which is roughly the same as the original version (from which, so far, 50% is shaved off).

Comment: Replacing matrix slices with the `sub` function might give a small boost, since any slice will allocate a temporary array.

Comment: Dear Colin, thanks for the suggestion! Do you have a reference regarding this behaviour? I thought standard indexing is merely a short form for slice, and sub is essentially slice but with slightly different behaviour regarding trailing dimensions, etc. With respect to the simulation code, all the slices are replaced by explicit loops now, so I am not sure how to use 'sub' in this case.

Comment: Check [here](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/) and do a word search on "SubArray". Indexing any *element* of an array does not allocate temporary memory. Indexing any *slice* of an array will create a temporary array corresponding to the slice. `sub` gets around this by creating a `SubArray` which is essentially a set of indices used to reference the original array. Operations on `SubArray` reference the original array rather than creating temporary array in memory, hence my original comment. However, all superfluous if you no longer have any slices :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you are using the `Devectorize.jl` package, I suggest that you just write out all of those vectorized operations explicitly as simple loops. I expect that this will give you a significant performance boost.

`Devectorize` package is certainly a great contribution, but to see the hoops it jumps through to do the dirty work for you, you can do something like this (an example from the package README):

```
using Devectorize

a = rand(2,2);
b = rand(2,2);
c = rand(2,2);

julia> macroexpand(:(@devec r = exp(a + b) .* sum(c)))
```

Here, `macroexpand` is a function that tells you the code to which the `@devec` macro expands its argument (the code on the rest of the line).
I won't spoil the surprise by showing the output here, but it is not just the simple `for` loop that you would write by hand.

Furthermore, the fact that you have huge allocation suggests that not all of the vector operations are being correctly dealt with.

By the way, don't forget to do a small run first so you are not timing the compilation step.

[Tangential note: here, `exp` is the function that applies the usual exponential function to each element of a matrix, equivalent to `map(exp, a+b)`.  `expm` gives the exponential of a matrix. There has been talk of deprecating such uses of `exp`.]

Comment: Dear David, thanks for the cool suggestion! Replacing the devec macro indeed shaves off 25% from the timings and allocations (see updated performance figures). Besides, macroexpand is a good thing to know about. Regarding testing the timings, I usually use the timeit macro with an additional compilation step before.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how this compares to a C or Fortran version. I wasn't really suggesting to go down to explicit BLAS calls, but it seems like that was a good idea.

Comment: By the way, you don't need .* to multiply a vector by a scalar, * will do.

Comment: Good point - the .* is a left-over from devectorize which actually requires this. I will also do a quick comparison with Cython now.

Comment: It would be interesting to replace all the BLAS calls with explicit loops in Julia and see how the performance changes.

Comment: I tried to replace the BLAS calls, but performance drops for anything larger then 10 units in the network.